# Make express.js route only accessible from local network

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, local

I'm trying to make certain routes only accessible from the servers local network (e.g. an admin view) with node.js / express.js

My idea is that it should work somehow like this:

```
//route.js

//...

router.get('/fancyURL', function (req, res) {
    // if req.origin.ip is in 192.168.xxx.xxx render the view
    // otherways deny access
});
```

but maybe there is a better/easier way to go. So what's the best way to acheive this?

Comment: I generally write a middleware, and simply add it to the callback list wherever I want to restrict/allow access.

Comment: https://github.com/tunnckocore/express-ip-filter